# Including section titles in fancyhf headers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to include the section name of the page's displayed section in my header tags in the fancyhdr package, something like

```
\fancyhf[HR]{SECTION NAME}
\fancyhf[HL]{SUBSECTION NAME}
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) provides this out-of-the-box and is not that different in interface/usage from [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). You might be interested in reading [`titleps` for `fancyhdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html).

If you wish to do this straight with `fancyhdr`, you'll have to patch the sectional unit constructions to store the titles, or use the title marks with some massaging.

You would use

```
\usepackage{titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps
\newpagestyle{main}{
\setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
\sethead{\subsectiontitle}% left
        {}%                 center
        {\sectiontitle}%    right
}
\pagestyle{main}
```

Here's a very minimal example with the addition of the sectional unit number as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps
\newpagestyle{main}{
\setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
\sethead{\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}% left
        {}%                                 center
        {\thesection\ \sectiontitle}%       right
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I will upvote you when I have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `fancyhdr` package for this task. I usually prepare several new commands to have full control of what will be shown in the header and footer. I enclose a small demonstration.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\myleft}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\myright}
\def\tomyleft#1{\def\myleft{#1}}
\def\tomyright#1{\def\myright{#1}}
\def\mysection#1#2{\section{#1}\tomyleft{#2}}
\def\mysubsection#1#2{\subsection{#1}\tomyright{#2}}
\begin{document}
\mysection{Welcome}{My welcome\ldots}
\mysubsection{Hello World!}{\ldots My Hello World!}
My first page.\newpage 
My second page.
\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]